# Удаление элемента на страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
Почему не удаляется элемент со страницы?

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="adv">
        Элемент, который нужно удалить
      </div>
      <div class="prompt" id="prompt">
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="javascript/js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

// js
var delet = document.getElementsByClassName("adv");
document.body.removeChild(delet);
```

```js
var delet = document.getElementsByClassName("adv");
document.body.removeChild(delet);
```

```html
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="adv">
    Элемент, который нужно удалить
  </div>
  <div class="prompt" id="prompt">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `delet[0].parentNode.removeChild(delet[0]);`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на ошибку, возникающую при выполнении фрагмента кода в вопросе. То, что возвращается из `getElementsByClassName`, не являeтся узлом DOM-дерева.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

```js
var delet = document.getElementsByClassName("adv");
if (delet[0]) {
  delet[0].parentNode.removeChild(delet[0]);
}
```

```html
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="adv">
    Элемент, который нужно удалить
  </div>
  <div class="prompt" id="prompt">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: почему вы сделали удаление через условие? а не просто написали delet[0].parentNode.removeChild(delet[0])

Comment: @Александр Если элементов с указанным классом на странице нет, обращение `delet[0].parentNode` приведет к ошибке и прерыванию выполнения скрипта.